# Google Places API - getPlacesPhotos() cannot be resolved

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google Places API to retrieve pictures of some places using the official method from their tutorial :

```
PlacePhotoMetadataResult result = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlacePhotos(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
```

But i have got an error in my IDE (Android studio) telling me that it cannot resolve the method `getPlacePhotos()`.

In `Places.GeoDataApi`, i can only call `getAutocompletePredictions()` or  `getPlaceById()`.

Anyone why i can't call `getPlacePhotos()` ?

Regards,

Comment: You'll need to upgrade to the latest version of the Google Play Services client library (7.8 at time of writing). You can do this by editing your build.gradle file so it has the following dependency: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`.

See the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its showing getPlacePhotos as public method in geoDataApi while describing functionalities. (Here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html )

Actual class definition does not have getPlacePhotos.  (last updated on august 20th) 
http://developer-android.ir/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html

Comment: So...Google is making a whole guide on a feature that is not implemented in their library ? O_o  https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/photos